# Meta-analysis using mixed-effects model with moderators where response variable is effect size - is it appropriate to remove the y-intercept?

Tags: r, meta-analysis, intercept

Greetings fellow statisticians,
We're working on a meta-analysis looking at the effect of mindfulness based interventions [MBI] on self-compassion. 
We've computed Hedges' `g` effect sizes for all studies included in the analysis and are using the values as a response variable in a mixed-effects Hunter-Schmidt regression model using `metafor` to examine what features of the MBIs exert significant influence on the self-compassion scores.

We currently have three time based features as continuous moderators: contact time (min), individual time (min), and duration (wks) with one additional derived time moderator: Immersiveness, constructed as follows:
`(Contact Time + Individual Time) / Duration`.

Additionally, there is a factor moderator, the type of intervention - ie if the MBI is modeled after MBSR or the Self Compassion Course.

I've consulted the documentation for `metafor` extensively, specifically the article on [Meta-Regression Models With or Without an Intercept](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:models_with_or_without_intercept), and other sources but don't feel confident making the call on my question without input.

The question is:
If my understanding is correct, setting the intercept to 0 (by adding `- 1` to the `mod` formula) effectively assumes that the response variable (on the y axis) is equal to 0 when the independent variable (on the x axis) is equal to 0. Extrapolated onto the specifics of our situation this would be equivalent to:

> if the moderator value is 0 (similar to a control group that didn't experience the intervention) then the effect size will be 0 (no change), ie there is no change on scores on the self-compassion scale if no intervention is delivered.

This seems like an appropriate assumption to make if I am correctly interpreting the effect of zeroing the intercept, though I would appreciate input and feedback from statisticians with more experience in meta-analysis to guide me. If you have any links to resources that consider this topic in more depth I would also greatly appreciate them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the intercept by changing mod(something) to mod(something - 1) you will get a coefficient for each level of the factor moderator. So the predicted value of the outcome is given by that coefficient. You can think of these are a set of intercepts, each corresponding to one level of the moderator. So in the case of a categorical moderator you do not remove the intercept in the same sense as when you have only continuous moderators. In that latter case you do indeed get the predicted value to be zero when the value(s) of the moderator(s) are all zero.

Comment: Hi @mdewey, thanks for the input!


> In that latter case you do indeed get the predicted value to be zero when the value(s) of the moderator(s) are all zero

This answered the main part of the question, much appreciated!
With regard to add `mod(something - 1)`, into the formula - this doesn't appear to work for `metafor::rma` mixed-effects models. I get the following error:

`Error in mod(\`Intervention Type\` - 1) : invalid unary operator`

If I just leave out the `mod` call, and add just `-1` at the end of the formula, the intercept is removed and all factor levels appear.

Comment: Not sure whether it is important but should there not be a ~ immediately after mod( in your comment?

Comment: I'm not sure? The metafor documentation indicated formulas were constructed like this:
`~ Moderator_name + Moderator_name` similar to `lm` formula but without the dependent variable. Am I writing the formula wrong?
Should it be:
`~ mod(something - 1) ~ mod(something_else - 1) ~ something_else2`
Or something of that nature?

Comment: I think the programming issue would be better on the mailing list as the comment space is not really helpful for posting full examples.